# error reading input file: Key has expired

Tags: linux, bash

I am currently making a bash script. The purpose of this script is not important. However, I have a piece of code that is generating an error. The error is as follows:

```
./script.bs: line 175: read: read error: 0: Key has expired
./script.bs: error reading input file: Key has expired
```

I have the code below for lines 175-189.

This specific piece of code does the following:
-Reads a txt file, that has a list of targeted files.
-For each targeted file, each line is read. And if that line is contained in $NumbersFile, it will do nothing. If that line is NOT contained in $NumbersFile, it will add that line to NumbersFile.

This general piece of code is working, and added 65810 lines of content to $NumbersFile. It then however got the error I stated above.

I'd like to add that the while loop on line 175 (where the error is happening) is supposed to read about 70'000 lines from the given file.

How do I fix this error so that my script may finish running without a key expired error?

```
NumbersFile="numbers.txt";
while read line; do

  while read gramline; do 
    has="0"; 
    if grep -Fq -- "$gramline" "$NumbersFile"; then
      has="1"; 
    fi 
    if [ "$has" -eq "0" ]; then 
      echo "$gramline" >> $NumbersFile; 
    fi 
  done < "$line";  
done < "targetsfile.txt";
```

Comment: Just fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: `Key has expired` is not a Bash error and nothing in your script seems to call on an external tool which might produce this error message. I'm vaguely guessing your file is on a remote server which uses some sort of authentication which times out after a while ...?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this code. numbers.txt is a file whose contents are filenames, one per line. For each of those files, you need to check if its contents also appear in numbers.txt. So you have a file containing filenames, and each of those files also contains filenames. Is that right? So every line of every file must be a file that exists, and they all have to be in numbers.txt

Comment: Hmm.... @tripleee you might be onto something. I am running this script from a network booted machine. I will try running it locally then I will get back to you.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `xargs cat <targetsfile.txt | awk '!($0 in a); {a[$0]}' >numbers.txt` if I untangled this correctly.

Comment: @glennjackman, I've clearly explained the purpose of this code. targetsfile.txt has a list of files of which contain 3-grams. Some of these files can be up to hundreds of thousands of lines long filled with 3-grams.

I am adding every single 3-gram from each targeted textfile into one big file called numbers.txt. numbers.txt may not contain the same 3-gram twice.

Comment: @tripleee you were correct about me doing this on a remote server. Allow me to run it locally. If the issue persists I will update my post.

Comment: You explained it, I just couldn't really believe it. You are doing a lot of IO which is slowing the process down: calling grep thousands of times, appending to the file thousands of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my comment is accurate, perhaps this might be faster:

```
{ cat targetsfile.txt; xargs cat < targetsfile.txt; } | sort -u > numbers.txt
```

Or as clarified:

```
xargs cat < targetsfile.txt | sort -u > numbers.txt
```

Notes:

- the braces are simply to group the cat and xargs commands so that the combined output can be piped into `sort`. Documented in the manual at [3.2.4.3 Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping)
- The first `cat` outputs the contents of the "targetsfile.txt" file
- the `xargs cat < targetsfile.txt` construct will execute the `cat` command for every file listed in the targets file. It's a very concise and efficient way to execute

  ```
  while IFS= read -r line; do cat "$line"; done < targetsfile.txt
  ```

Comment: I was thinking something similar, but the sorting may be undesirable.

Comment: This is interesting. I will try this out later as well. Thanks for the valuable input.

Comment: @glennjackman since I am new to bash. I'm not sure exactly what your code does before the piping. As in, why do you have curly braces in the syntax, and why are you using the cat command twice? When I try to run this on the terminal it doesn't execute, it just puts me to a newline.

Comment: I bet it does execute, but all the output is redirected to the numbers file. Verify that it contains the expected contents.

Comment: Update. It is executing now. I must have inputted something improperly. Forgive me as I'm still learning about bash, and I will be for years to come. I will notify you later about the correctness of the results.

Comment: Hi @glennjackman, that ran way faster than I thought it would. It does not give the proper output as it also outputs the contents of targetsfile.txt onto numbers.txt. However, this was fixed by piping. I have re-modified the code to: 
{ cat targetsfile.txt | xargs cat < targetsfile.txt; } | sort -u > numbers.txt

All I did was change the ';' to '|' in the brackets.

Comment: Since you don't need that content, just do `xargs cat < targetsfile.txt | sort -u > numbers.txt` -- the input redirection `>` will override the pipe anyway.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman. I'm sure that this is giving me the results I need.

Comment: I'm curious about the difference in execution time. Do you have a feel for how long the two approaches take?

Comment: hi @glennjackman, the execution time is about 5 minutes with your code. With my initial code it would take more than a day (assuming it doesn't get the key error).

Comment: Good to hear. tripleee's awk filter could be even faster

Comment: If I am to understand this properly, Input Output operations are incredibly costly to do. Which is why my code is expensive.

Comment: yes. Also costly is launching a new process (as in "grep" in your original code). When you only need to do it a few dozen times, the cost is negligible but in the thousands, those milliseconds really add up. With the technique you've learned here, although you have to open and read every file (with "cat"), you only write the output once. This is the power of unix pipes.

Comment: One thing to be careful of: with shell redirection you cannot use input and output redirection. Don't do this: `myprogram < file > file` -- the shell processes the redirections *before* launching the program, and the output redirection `>` will **truncate** the file to zero bytes: the program will find the input file is empty.

Comment: Anyway, good luck with your shell journey. You'll find that the [bash tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) has boatloads of useful information.

Comment: Thank you very much